# How can I use jQuery/JS to make the enter row (<tr>) dissappear when I click the <a>

Tags: jquery, dom

This is pretty embarrassing I can't even think of where to start.

I have a number of table rows that look like this. How can I create some jQuery that will allow the x to be clicked causing the enter row to be deleted from the DOM.

I can of course hard code some tags into the code and make it work for this specific case, however I want it to work for an arbitrary number of similar rows. This is where my brain is failing me at the moment.

```
<tr><td>Well Name - <span class="urlOfProperty">http://mycompany.com/type/well-name</span>
  <div class="close">[<a href="#">x</a>]</div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method in jquery:

```
$(".close a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

(or use a delegate, may be more suited on your specific task):

```
$("table").on("click", ".close a", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

code example is for jQuery 1.7+

if you are using a lower version you can use this:

```
$("table").delegate(".close a", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

a bit of a warning, this will bind the event on all your tables in your document, change the table selector to be a bit more unique maybe.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I'll upgrade jQuery and give it a go.

Comment: @Ankur have added code for jQuer <1.7 if you can´t upgrade jQuery (may have a plugin that don´t work in the latest version of jQuery).

Comment: I just tried your newer code and it worked perfectly with jquery 1.6.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

add a "my_table" id on your table and use this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#my_table").on('click','.close',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```